# Replacing default file manager without breaking browsing within File Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry

In attempt to change a default file manager I have tried replacing command location under

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\open\command`

and

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\explore\command`

(and also for "Folder" instead of "Directory", but it looks like the difference is only that Folder includes Directory but also non-filesystem items like Control panel items, which I don't want to be handled anyway)

The issue is that replacing `open\command` will also open new file manager when user doubleclicks on a folder in Explorer. My assumption was that Explore is navigation within Explorer and Open is used external, but it isn't. Is this even possible?

Comment: A decent file manager (e.g. xPlorer2 or others) do not need extra registry entries to work.

Comment: @John This is both unhelpful and untrue. I have just installed that xplorer2 in VM to test and it also breaks Explorer which I didn't want (see last paragraph - doubleclick folder in Explorer will launch xplorer2 breaking navigation in Explorer and making it useless)

Comment: I have been using xPlorer2 for so long I have a lifetime license. I do not need to muck with the registry to make File Explorer, xPlorer2, Tree Size, or Total Commander to work. There is something wrong with your OS.

Comment: I will go so far as to say that if you have been using the registry as a User Tool, you are very most likely looking at backup and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @John Open Explorer to c:\, Doubleclick on Windows folder - xPlorer2 opens - which means xPlorer2 breaks Explorer. The same happens in Windows Sandbox or VirtualBox, meaning that it happens on a completely clean WIndows image without any registry changes. xPlorer2 breaks Explorer regardless

Comment: There is something wrong with your situation. I have had xPlorer2 running Windows 7, 8, 10 and 11 with zero breakage.  File Explorer runs alongside.  I do not understand your situation. Are you using a proper Microsoft ISO to create the VM?  Are you using a language that xPlorer does not have?

Comment: @John Try the above steps. Run Windows Sandbox that comes with Windows 10/11 and install xplorer there. That is as clean system image as it gets. Doubleclick on any folder in Explorer opens xplorer. Everything is default

Comment: I will work on it. Windows Sandbox is secure so I have not been able to get a file into i. Even assuming that works I do not know what it proves. You may wish to answer my question about language.  I will need to make an XML file to reconfig Sandbox.

Comment: I had to give up on Sandbox - This is not a working machine so who know what might happen. But that has nothing to do with normal machines running xPlorer2 or any other replacement I have running here. Year after year, computer after computer xPlorer2 works, Tree Size works and Total Commander works. What computer language are you using?

Comment: Trying to map a folder in Sandbox crashed my Insider machine. No go.

Comment: @John Don't bother. I hoped there was something new. xplorer2 is the same old tech as when it was made in 2002 and TC is from 93, so I wouldn't expect much. I am in IT for 15 years and use Sandbox, HyperV and VirtualBox all the time. Either there isn't way to keep explorer functionality or you just don't know

Comment: I got the newest xPloer2 this past weekend. Maybe try that